# Can't see NodeJS configuration in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed NodeJS plugin on Jenkins, linux host. 
When I go to /configure I can't see NodeJS configuration

Anyone have this trouble ?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `/configureTools` instead of `/configure`